# 1980s Graphic comic Adult Science fiction short stories

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a graphic science fiction comic collection of short stories. One story involves  deformed mutants being taken from Earth to another planet; the pilots of the spaceship were normal and had to live with the mutants. They would put masks over the girls because they were so repulsive before having sex with them. They waited years for another space ship would come for them. When it did they thought they would be going back to Earth but found that everyone was now a deformed mutant. There would have been about 10-12 short stories in the magazine.

Comment: Where did you read this? In which language?

Comment: Was it in color or black and white? You're sure the comic was from the 80s? Or did you read it in the 80s? If it could be older, I'd suggest some of EC Comics' sci-fi runs, like the 50s' Weird Science, Weird Fantasy, or others, or some of the later reprints of those.

Comment: Most likely candidates from the USA in the 80's, especially given the number of stories, are *Heavy Metal*, *1984*/*1994*, and *Epic illustrated*.

Comment: It was in Black and white English I believe it could have been about 1977 was  a new cheap type comic was all a bit of a haze back then but definitely did read.